# Cálculo aritmético entre constantes dá errado (C - GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, constantes

Tenho definidas as seguintes constantes:

```
#define AMOUNT 100
#define QBUCKETS AMOUNT / 30 + (AMOUNT % 30 != 0)
#define LIM_INFERIOR 0
#define LIM_SUPERIOR 500
#define GAP (LIM_INFERIOR + LIM_SUPERIOR) / QBUCKETS
```

O valor de `QBUCKETS` está sendo corretamente definido para 4, neste caso de quando `AMOUNT` vale 100. No entanto, a `GAP` atribuído o valor 1. O resultado dessa operação deveria ser (0 + 500) / 4 = 125.

```
printf("%i %i %i\n", LIM_INFERIOR, LIM_SUPERIOR, QBUCKETS);
printf("%i", (LIM_INFERIOR + LIM_SUPERIOR) / QBUCKETS);
```

Imprime:

```
0 500 4
1
```

Se eu substituir o nome das constantes pelos seus respectivos valores, dentro do segundo `printf`, vou obter o resultado correto do cálculo. O que está causando esse comportamento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na definição de `QBUCKETS`. Ela é, *ipsis literis*:

```
AMOUNT / 30 + (AMOUNT % 30 != 0)
```

Esta definição é simplesmente copiada para a definição de `GAP`:

```
GAP (LIM_INFERIOR + LIM_SUPERIOR) / AMOUNT / 30 + (AMOUNT % 30 != 0)
```

E como a divisão é uma operação não associativa, o resultado acaba dando errado porque `AMOUNT` deveria ser dividido por `30 + (AMOUNT % 30 != 0)` antes de dividir `(LIM_INFERIOR + LIM_SUPERIOR)`. Ao isolar a definição de `AMOUNT` com parênteses, o cálculo passa a dar certo.

Comment: Importante avisar que isso ocorre porque essas definições são macros, por isso são resolvidas dessa forma, e antes da compilação